# Why is a relay controlling a roller shutter constantly at ~50°C?

Tags: relay, temperature

I have several [Shelly 2.5 controllers](https://shelly.cloud/products/shelly-25-smart-home-automation-relay/) for my roller shutters. They work great but I noticed that the temperature they report is stable around 50°C.

When reading relevant forums, it seems that nobody is particularly worried about that temperature. I got to wonder where that temperature can come from.

They are only used twice a day for 30 seconds and otherwise stay idle, so no coil current. They do have a WiFi connection that is always up, so this may be the reason. But 50°C seems quite a lot, compared to a phone for instance.

Is there a general reason for such devices to be that hot?

Comment: I think that for this to be on-topic you'd need to give us schematics, datasheet and some photos rather than just a link to a brochure.

Comment: Use your hand to feel the temperature of the enclosure.  It is entirely possible that the internal power supply is not particularly efficient.  50C is not what I would consider to be excessive.

Comment: @Transistor: I understand (and will close the question because there are no publicly available schematics). I was more interested in the general question of why such solid state relays would be hot when they are not in use. But I understand that this is too broad. Thanks.

Comment: Are the controllers actually hot (feel them with your hand)?  That temperature reading may just be a default value when there is no temperature sensor installed.

Comment: @PeterBennett: yes they are. Since they are enclosed in an electric box (the kind you use when you have cable junctions) I cannot have a precise reading but the box feels hot on the touch (not piping hot, just really warm). I see some small variations of the temperature on my monitoring system (roughly 50-52°C)

Comment: Are they dark coloured, and in sunshine during the day?

Comment: There's plenty of writeups regarding this along with thermal pictures. The NTC used to measure the temperature is coupled to the ESP8266 - it's not measuring the ambient temperature. Note that the Shelly 2.5 is not a solid state relay - it uses normal electromagnetic relays. solid state relays are a different beast. You also can't compare it to a phone - two totally different devices. The Shelly is a low cost device built to a price. 50C is not an unreasonable or dangerous temperature. Don't expect these things to last more than a couple of years.

Comment: something seems wring with them. They spec up to 40C for operation, and claim to consume under 1W, which likely cannot get a box that large that hot. Maybe the coils are (almost) always on and you have them wired to NC...